# Why my product stock and stable quantity are not equal?

Tags: magento2

I'm selling this product and add 7 into stocks but the default stock is showing only 4.Customer can buy only 4.

[image]

What is the Default Stock? And how can I make it equal to my real quantitys that I added to the stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is added in Magento 2.3, the Quantity of a product does not decrease when an order is placed. Instead, the quantity remains the same but Salable Quantity gets reduced. The quantity of the product decrease only after shipping is completed.

Hope that answers your question.